# Compilation error in scala

Tags: scala, compiler-errors

I'm a newbie in scala. I recently started using netbeans for writing scala programs.I have installed scala version 2.11.0.400 and its plugins for netbeans.When I try to compile my scala code:-

```
package scalaapplication2

object Main {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit=
  {
    println("Hello, world!")
  }

}
```

I get the following compilation error even after setting the path variables:-

```
  Compiling 1 source file to C:\Users\Nitin\Documents\NetBeansProject\ScalaApplication2\build\classes

  C:\Users\Nitin\Documents\NetBeansProjects\ScalaApplication2\nbproject\build-   impl.xml:423:

  The following error occurred while executing this line:

  C:\Users\Nitin\Documents\NetBeansProjects\ScalaApplication2\nbproject\build-impl.xml:238: bad option: '-make:transitive'
```

Why is it so?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Removing '-make:transitive' from the scalac addparams option (Files view > ScalaApplication > nbproject > build-impl.xml) worked for me.

Comment: And for those using Maven, it's often included in the configuration of the `scala-maven-plugin` (e.g. when using archetypes). Remove that arg from your POM and things should be fine.

Comment: BTW, I've raised this issue with the author of the scala-archetype-simple archetype: [-make:transitive not playing nice with Scala 2.11 #8](https://github.com/davidB/scala-archetype-simple/issues/8)

Comment: I'm using maven but i am not using the plugin, still the error pops up.