# Scala Hello World program fails to compile in netbeans IDE

Tags: scala, netbeans

I am getting the following error when compiling a Hello World Program in Netbeans.

`C:\Users\Norman\Documents\NetBeansProjects\LambdaCollectionExamples\ScalaApplication2\nbproject\build-impl.xml:238: bad option: '-make:transitive'.`

This is the xml file:-

```
<scalac addparams="-make:transitive -dependencyfile  &quot;${basedir}/${build.dir}/.scala_dependencies&quot; @{addparams}" 
        deprecation="${scalac.deprecation}" 
        destdir="@{destdir}" 
        encoding="${source.encoding}" excludes="@{excludes}" 
        extdirs="@{extdirs}" 
        force="yes" 
        fork="true" 
        includes="@{includes}" 
        sourcepath="@{sourcepath}" 
        srcdir="@{srcdir}" 
        target="jvm-${javac.target}" 
        unchecked="${scalac.unchecked}">
```

This is the program

```
package scalaapplication2

object Main {

  /**
   * @param args the command line arguments
   */
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    println("Hello, world!")
  }

}
```

Comment: Try adding -make:transitive options to command-line.I hope it generates a file which will resolve your issue.

Comment: The correct answer is to remove the text `-make:transitive` from `build-impl.xml` as explained in [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25104954/243233). This is not the best answer as its a bug in the Scala plugin for NB. [This NB Scala plugin patch](https://github.com/dcaoyuan/nbscala/pull/130) may solve it (haven't tested it myself).

Answer (score 0):

Scala 2.11.2 was giving me such errors. Download Scala 2.10.4 binaries for your system should resolve it.

```
ant -f C:\\Users\\wayne\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\ScalaApplication2 run
init:
deps-jar:
Compiling 1 source file to C:\Users\wayne\Documents\NetBeansProjects\ScalaApplication2\build\classes
Recompiling 1 files
warning: there were 1 deprecation warning(s); re-run with -deprecation for details
one warning found
compile:
run:
Hello, world!
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 3 seconds)
```