# Can't set up Scala on Netbeans (Linux Mint)

Tags: scala, netbeans, plugins, linux-mint

I have been trying to install scala on Netbeans on a Linux Mint 18.1 machine, following :quite unsuccessfully thus far and I am in need of advice. The steps I have taken thus ffollowing:

- Install Netbeans & JVM bundle
- Download scala 2.12.1 from https://www.scala-lang.org/download/
- Set in /etc/environment the PATH to include the untar directory of scala
- Append "-J-Dscalahome=..." on ~/NetBeans/etc/netbeans.conf
- Append "$SCALA_HOME=..." on .bashrc
- Install the scala plugin for Netbeans from here https://sourceforge.net/projects/erlybird/files/nb-scala/7.x_2.10.x/

...and tried to run the default scala "Hello World" program, just to make sure it is working. What I got on the console is the following

> ant -f /home/vbent/NetBeansProjects/ScalaApplication2 run init:
>   deps-jar: Compiling 1 source file to
>   /home/vbent/NetBeansProjects/ScalaApplication2/build/classes
>   /home/vbent/NetBeansProjects/ScalaApplication2/nbproject/build-impl.xml:405:
>   The following error occurred while executing this line:
>   /home/vbent/NetBeansProjects/ScalaApplication2/nbproject/build-impl.xml:238:
>   bad option: '-make:transitive' BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)

How do I correct this ?? I haven't the foggiest idea what to do from this point on. Please be very descriptive and detailed on your answers as I am new to Linux and thus easily confused.

Thank you in advance for your time.

Comment: Please refer to the answers in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23875515/compilation-error-in-scala

Comment: I have done so but i can't understand the answer given... It says  "the scalac addparams option (Files view > ScalaApplication > nbproject > build-impl.xml)" ... where is that ?? I can't find anything named "Files View"...

Comment: it is here `/home/vbent/NetBeansProjects/ScalaApplication2/nbproject/build-impl.xml`

Comment: Thank you again for the time you took to answer my question. Just let me clarify this : I have to correct this each and every time i start a new Scala project, the respective build-impl.xml ??  There is no way to fix this once and for all somehow, just "on demand", so to speak ??

Comment: There probably is. However, since you are pretty new to all this, I would recommend that you handle it manually for a while until you are comfortable with netbeans, scala, xml etc.